# Wordpress featured images won't display

Tags: php

I am creating a widget in wordpress that pulls through child pages content (thumbnail/Featured image, title and excerpt) from the 'About Page' and displays them on the 'Homepage'. All content except the thumbnail/featured displays correctly. The thumbnail/featured image displays in grey, is is viable in other post and in the back end. when I inspect the code the url for the image does not seem to be pulling through.

Can anyone assist with this issue?

```
    $pgs = array(

      'parent' => '344', 
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 99,
      'orderby' => 'menu_order'
    );

    $pages = get_pages( $pgs );

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    ?>

    <div class="text-center">
        <h2 class="blessed-widget-title">title</h2>

        <div class="text-center" id="services">

        <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) {  ?>

            <div class="our-services-post-box col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="child-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
                    <div class="service-thumbnail background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo blessed_get_attachment($page->ID) ?>) ">
                        <img class="image-invisible" src=" <?php echo blessed_get_attachment($page->ID); ?> ">
                    </div>
                    <h2><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h2>
                </a>

                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt($page->ID) ?></p>

            </div><!--services-->

        <?php } ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php

    echo $args['after_widget'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 missed semicolons.

1st was here:

```
<div class="service-thumbnail background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo blessed_get_attachment($page->ID) ?>) ">
```

2nd was here:

```
<p><?php echo get_the_excerpt($page->ID) ?></p>
```

Maybe it caused the problem. Also Quotes are not necessary in an url, but I added it to see what will be the result.

Try to use the following one instead.

```
$pgs = array(

      'parent' => '344', 
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 99,
      'orderby' => 'menu_order'
    );

    $pages = get_pages( $pgs );

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    ?>

    <div class="text-center">
        <h2 class="blessed-widget-title">title</h2>

        <div class="text-center" id="services">

        <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) {  ?>

            <div class="our-services-post-box col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" id="child-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $page->post_title; ?>">
                    <div class="service-thumbnail background-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo blessed_get_attachment($page->ID); ?>') ">
                        <img class="image-invisible" src=" <?php echo blessed_get_attachment($page->ID); ?> ">
                    </div>
                    <h2><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h2>
                </a>

                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt($page->ID); ?></p>

            </div><!--services-->

        <?php } ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php

    echo $args['after_widget'];
```

Also try to review your CSS Classes related to Featured images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply to my question, i tried the amended code, but the url still isn't being pulled through.  I don't understand why this isn't working, as it works for other posts and pages.

Comment: Do you mean the code doesn't work for specific posts only?